# Trouble Installing PythonMagick Windows 7

Tags: python-2.7, imagemagick

I am trying to install PythonMagick. I am using Python 2.7 and running Windows 7.  I have tried following the directions in the readme, but all of the configuration scripts are of type "file" and cannot be executed in either the python or windows command line. What should I do?

Comment: You have go provide some more context here. What happens when you try to execute them? How do you try and execute them?

Comment: I get the phrase "not an executable file" when I type the command as is written in the readme

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I recommend you use the [pre-compiled installer](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pythonmagick) from the [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Just follow [this link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pythonmagick) and download the right installer for your Python interpreter (in your case it will either be `PythonMagick-0.9.10.win-amd64-py2.7.‌exe` or `PythonMagick-0.9.10.win32-py2.7.‌exe`, depending on whether you've installed the **64** or **32** bit Python interpreter).

Comment: Once again, the Unofficial Windows Binaries save the day

Comment: do you need anything else installed on Windows to make it work? I have a DLL issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538973/pythonmagick-on-windows-dll-load-failed