# Confused on how to install PythonMagick module

Tags: python, pythonmagick

Use Case - I'm trying to convert TIFF to PDFs and I stumbled on PythonMagick .9 but I have trouble installing it.

Most of the questions I have found both here and from Google are related to older versions of PythonMagick which leads to dead links or the tutorial is used for MACs. How can I install it on Windows (using Python 2.7) or should I not use PythonMagick? Thanks

Edit: Or if there is an updated installer guide that would be great.

Comment: Download and run the installer.

Comment: Try the binaries at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pythonmagick

Comment: I see the zip file from their site http://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/ but there isn't an installer in there. It is more of not intuitive to me on what to do with these files.

Comment: Try this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409643/trouble-installing-pythonmagick-windows-7

Comment: cgohlke- Yes I have looked into that, installed wheel to read the .whl file extensions and I am sure it is not working since the mod is not there. Also, some people say that "boost" is a dependency of PythonMagick but it has also the same of dead ends and such.

Comment: Bot-13 - Yes it is the same link as what cgohlke has provided but those exe do not exist anymore.

Comment: Sorry about that short hand, mod = module.

Comment: I installed wheel, ran the necessary file with the .whl extension and ran into an error
Error: The application has failed to start because the side by side configuration is incorrect please see the application event log or use the command line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail
So I installed a C++ redistribute package and it ran but it gave an error about the kernel unexpectedly dying.

Answer (score 0):

You can download it from https://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/, As it maintained by the Debian repo, So you could't install it by pip or easy_install.

Comment: So how do I install? Please let me know the installation procedure.